# Reledmac XeLaTeX Arabic: Line wrapping does not work in Critical footnotes

Tags: xetex, arabic, reledmac, arabxetex

I ran into an issue of Reledmac with XeLaTeX. The line wrapping in critical footnotes is not working as expected, instead, the line extends and bleeds to the margins. I am Giving the following MWE for illustration. I appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noeledsec,noledgroup,noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage{arabxetex} \let\textarabic\relax \let\Arabic\relax 
\setdefaultlanguage[locale=algeria]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1]{Amiri}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX}, Scale=1]{Junicode}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\parafootsepX{$\parallel$~}
\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$~}
\makeatletter
\let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
وفي الباب الحادي والعشرين أنّ «يَسُوعَ أرسل 
\edtext{اثنين من تلاميذه}{\Afootnote{في ن1 تلميذ واحد. في ن 5 إثنين من أصحابه.  في ن1 تلميذ واحد. في ن 5 إثنين من أصحابه.  في ن1 تلميذ واحد. في ن 5 إثنين من أصحابه.  في ن1 تلميذ واحد. في ن 5 إثنين من أصحابه. }} وقال لهما: اِذْهَبَا إِلَى الْقَرْيَةِ الَّتِي أَمَامَكُمَا، فتَجِدَانِ سريعا أَتَانًا\footnoteA{في هذا الموضع تنتهي ن\LR{5}.} مَرْبُوطَةً وَجَحْشًا مَعَهَا، فَحلاّهُمَا وَاتِيَاني بِهِمَا، فَإِنْ قَالَ لَكُمَا أَحَدٌ شَيْئًا، فَقُولاَ إنّ الرَّبَّ مُحْتَاجٌ إِلَيْهِمَا، فهو يُرْسِلُهُمَا لِلْوَقْتِ. فذهَبَا وَصَنَعا كَمَا أَمَرَهُمَا يَسُوعُ، وَأَتَيَا بِالأَتَانِ وَالْجَحْشِ، وتركوا ثِيَابَهُمَا عَلَيْهِمَا وأجلَسوه فوقهما» انتهى\footnoteA{إنجيل \textbf{متَّى}، الأصحَاحُ الحادي والعشرون، \LR{01}–\LR{07}.}. ومثله في التاسع عشر من إنجيل «لوقا»\footnoteA{إنجيل \textbf{لُوقَا}، الأصحَاحُ التاسع عشر، \LR{29}–\LR{35}.}.

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```